# What is the acceleration of the large block?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string

The answer was given mg/(2M+m). I found this one and cannot find where i made the mistake....
[image]

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 2):

I havent learnt about Langrangian, but this question can be solved using simple dynamics equation.

Here is an approach: take tension of the strings attached to the small blocks to be T. Tension of the string attached to the larger block is 2T. There will be no normal force exerted on the freely falling body as friction is negligible.

Comment: I have newly learnt lagrangian.  I've already solved it with newton's laws. They provided the solution added in the answers. But I wanted to do this with lagrangian....